# Assign Portlet Macro Path in eea.facetednavigation

Tags: portlet, plone

I want to add a 'Plone portlet' widget in Faceted criteria config screen. In particular, here I need a static portlet to add URL links. How do I fill the 'Portlet macro' field for a static portlet? Helper message is 'Path to portlet macro', and I already try values like 'here/portlet_static/macros/portlet' and 'here/portlet_recent/macros/portlet', all failed.

Plone 4.0.2 + eea.facetednavigation 4.0rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `eea.facetednavigation` but it sounds to me like you have a bad mix of portlet technologies.

The `/macros/portlet` slot was only available in classic portlets based on simple templates as used in Plone 2.5. Since Plone 3 we have a completely different portlet machinery which no longer has any TAL macros in them.

As far as I know the EEA site is still using Plone 2.5 - so I wouldn't be surprised if many of their add-ons aren't compatible with later versions of Plone.

Comment: Thanks, Hanno. Your answer helps a lot. While hoping there's generic Plone portlet support soon, my quick workaround is hacking into its browser/template/widgets.pt and adding `<div tal:condition="python: context.id == 'myfolder'">`.